# get_queried_object()->image ; cannot get image

Tags: php, wordpress, taxonomy, custom-taxonomy

I have created a custom taxonomy for products. In custom taxonomy user can enter name and can upload a image. In the products page I can get the image and title of category. When user clicks on this it moves to next page where description of post and title is shown.

I also want to get image also in this next page.

**Here is the code: For showing custom categories**

```
foreach($terms as $term) {

    $prod_meta = get_option("taxonomy_term_".$term->term_id);

    if(($counter % 4) == 0) {
        echo '<div class="row product-gallery">';
    }
    ?>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="product-warp">
            <div class="product">
                <a href="#"><img src="<?php echo $prod_meta['img']; ?>" title="" alt=""></a>
            </div>
            <div class="product-name">
                <h5>
                    <a href="<?php echo get_term_link($term->slug, 'product_categories') ?>">
                        <?php echo $term->name; ?>
                    </a>
                </h5>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**For product detail page**

```
<?php
get_header();

$slug = get_queried_object()->slug; // get clicked category slug
$name = get_queried_object()->name; // get clicked category name

$tax_post_args = array(
    'post_type' => 'products', // your post type
    'posts_per_page' => 999,
    'orderby' => 'id',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_categories', // your taxonomy
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => $slug
        )
    )
);
$tax_post_qry = new WP_Query($tax_post_args);

if ($tax_post_qry->have_posts())
    while($tax_post_qry->have_posts()) :
        $tax_post_qry->the_post(); ?>

        <div class="row product-details">
        <div class="col-sm-7">
        <div class="fire-product">
        <h4><?php the_title(); ?></h4>

        <?php the_content(); ?>
```

Comment: So what is the problem you are facing ?

Comment: i want to get the image also

Comment: please can you tell me ... what is your wordpress version now